Renew ConfidentialClientApplication when client secret is expired
I am unsure how to use correctly the confidentialClientApplication by Microsoft in my Azure Functions.
I have the following code:
public class OAuthService
{
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication;
    private static readonly string[] scopes = ["https://blabla"];

    public OAuthService()
    {
        confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("clientId")
            .WithClientSecret(getClientSecretFromKeyVault())
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetOAuthTokenAsync(Guid tenantId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Get OAuthToken for tenant {tenantId}");
        return await confidentialClientApplication
            .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId.ToString())
            .ExecuteAsync();
    }
}

As I want to reuse the same confidentialClientApplication, and the accesstokens it generates, I have added this class as a singleton.
services.AddSingleton<OAuthService>();
As far as I know, this works great, because I can easily call GetOAuthTokenAsync, and it will get me an AccessToken. However, The clientSecret used in the Builder is expiring very soon. What will happen if this clientSecret is expired? I have updated the clientSecret in the KeyVault. How can I make sure the new clientSecret is picked up correctly from the KeyVault?
If I am registering this OAuthService class as a transient one, it solves this problem, but with every call to my Function App it builds a new confidentialClientApp and therefore doesn't reuse the accesstoken. This is not what I want, for obvious performance reasons.
I was thinking in some way of resetting the singleton daily or something, but that doesn't feel the right way. The Azure Function App should not have any downtime. Am I missing something?

Are you passing the AzureKeyvault URI and secret name in the local.settings.json with the updated secret when the old secret has expired or automatically taking the updated secret from Azure Keyvault using the URI in the local.settings.json.

Is your local.setting.json look like this {
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connec_string>",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
},
"KeyVaultUri": "https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/",
"ClientSecretName": "<secret_name>"
}

@DasariKamali, Yes, the 'keyvault uri' and 'secret name' are in the settings.json. When I get a new ClientSecret, I will update this exact keyvault secret with the new ClientSecret. Basically I create a new version of this secret in Keyvault

If the client secret for your ConfidentialClientApplication has expired. In that case, you need to create a new secret, store it in Azure Key Vault, and use it in the following Azure HTTP trigger Function code to obtain the access token.
Code :
Function1.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly OAuthService oAuthService;
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> logger;

        public Function1(OAuthService oAuthService, ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            this.oAuthService = oAuthService;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            if (!Guid.TryParse(req.Query["tenantId"], out var tenantId))
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid tenantId.");
            }

            var result = await oAuthService.GetOAuthTokenAsync(tenantId);
            return new OkObjectResult(result.AccessToken);
        }
    }
}

OAuthService.cs :
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class OAuthService
    {
        private IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication;
        private static readonly string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        private readonly IKeyVaultService keyVaultService;
        private string currentClientSecret;
        private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        private readonly ILogger<OAuthService> logger;

        public OAuthService(IKeyVaultService keyVaultService, ILogger<OAuthService> logger)
        {
            this.keyVaultService = keyVaultService;
            this.logger = logger;
            InitializeConfidentialClientApplication();
        }

        private void InitializeConfidentialClientApplication()
        {
            currentClientSecret = keyVaultService.GetClientSecretFromKeyVault();
            confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("<client_ID>") //Replace your clientID here
                .WithClientSecret(currentClientSecret)
                .Build();
        }

        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetOAuthTokenAsync(Guid tenantId)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                var newClientSecret = keyVaultService.GetClientSecretFromKeyVault();
                if (newClientSecret != currentClientSecret)
                {
                    currentClientSecret = newClientSecret;
                    InitializeConfidentialClientApplication();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }

            logger.LogInformation($"Get OAuthToken for tenant {tenantId}");
            return await confidentialClientApplication
                .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId.ToString())
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }
}

KeyVaultService.cs :
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class KeyVaultService : IKeyVaultService
    {
        private readonly SecretClient secretClient;
        private readonly string clientSecretName;

        public KeyVaultService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var keyVaultUri = configuration["KeyVaultUri"];
            var credentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                AdditionallyAllowedTenants = { "<tenant_ID>" } //Replace your tenantID her
            };
            secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential(credentialOptions));
            clientSecretName = configuration["ClientSecretName"];
        }

        public string GetClientSecretFromKeyVault()
        {
            KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret(clientSecretName);
            return secret.Value;
        }
    }

    public interface IKeyVaultService
    {
        string GetClientSecretFromKeyVault();
    }
}

Startup.cs :
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp4.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKeyVaultService, KeyVaultService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<OAuthService>();
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
        }
    }
}

You should pass the Azure Keyvault URL and Secret name in the below local.settings.json.
local.settings.json :
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connec_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "KeyVaultUri": "https://<keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/",
  "ClientSecretName": "<secret_name>"
}

I gave the Application.ReadWrite.All permissions under the API permissions in the Azure AD app as below,

I gave access to the Azure Function app and Azure AD app to Get and List in the Azure Key vault access policies as below,

Note: Before going to run the above code, ensure you have added the below details in your System Environment variables.
AZURE_CLIENT_ID = <client_ID>
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET = <client_secret>
AZURE_TENANT_ID = <tenant_ID>

I passed the below HTTP trigger function URL with the tenant ID in the browser and got the Access token.
http://localhost:7209/api/Function1?tenantId=<tenant_ID>


Output :
The following code ran successfully as below.


Thanks for your thourough answer! However, a few questions. Why using a semaphore inside the GetOAuthTokenAsync()? if it's a singleton, it doesn't add much to it?
And secondly, in this solution, you need to trigger the Azure Function to renew the clientSecret. Isn't there some automated way inside c#, without using external Azure Functions?
